# Did this following code apply late binding onto a static method? Polymorphism Java

Tags: java, dynamic, binding, static, polymorphism

So I was playing around in Java to understand the concept of polymorphism, and I wrote this:

```
public class Practice 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Parent p = new Child();
        
        p.instanceMethod();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
     public void instanceMethod(){
         System.out.println("child's instance method");
         staticMethod();
     }
     public static void staticMethod() {
         System.out.println("child's static method");
     }
}

class Parent {
     public void instanceMethod(){
         System.out.println("parent's instance method");
         staticMethod();
     }
     public static void staticMethod() {
         System.out.println("parent's static method");
     }
}
```

So the output of this is:

```
child's instance method
child's static method
```

Why is the the static method called upon from the child's class and not from it's static type, Parent's class?

Is it because, it is first called by the instance method in child's class, so at that point its type is already fully dynamic, aka child's type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static methods don't 'do' polymorphism. At all.

non-static (i.e. instance) methods do. The **signature** of the method is bound entirely statically; the actual prospect of finding which method to actually run in the type hierarchy is done entirely dynamically (late binding).

For static methods, the entire thing is entirely static.

So, let's go through this code:

### `p.instanceMethod()`

The expression `p` is of type `Parent`. The compiler looks at the signatures available in `Parent` and all its supertypes and determines that the full method signature that this invocation of `instanceMethod()` is attempting to invoke is `void instanceMethod()`. This call (`Parent`::`instanceMethod()V` in bytecode speak) is encoded in the emitted .class file.

At runtime, the system checks the actual runtime type of what the `p` expression resolves to (which is the `new Child()` you did earlier), and does dynamic dispatch. The `public void instanceMethod()` of `Child`, which clearly overrides the one from `Parent`, is selected and executed, therefore, `"child's instance method"` is printed.

### `staticMethod()` in Child

Next, let's look at that staticMethod invoke: at compile time, javac determines that this is clearly a reference to the `staticMethod()` that's right there, in `Child`. It encodes, in the bytecode an `INVOKESTATIC` bytecode to `Child`::`staticMethod()V`. Dynamic dispatch is not now or ever applied to static method calls.

At runtime.. that method is called.

Simple as that.

Perhaps you expected that a static method still first checks the call context but that's not how java works.

Comment: So it'll be the static method of the child class that is called, because that static method is called by an instance method of the child class, so by then, the "environment" is already in the child class. Does that make sense? Because if we'd directly call a staticMethod() onto 'p', it would be the staticMethod from parent's class instead.

Comment: Sure. The binding is decided solely by where that call is. The language feature that lets you write 'p.staticMethod();' is a fluke that _EVERY_ linter tool, including javac itself, will tell you is a language error that cannot be removed because java remains backwards compatible. In other words, who cares? You should never do that. You'd write Parent.staticMethod() or Child.staticMethod(). Note that there is no relationship between Parent.staticMethod() and Child.staticMethod().

Comment: Thanks, I was concerned that something like that might be a question on my exam. But your explanation clears up the bigger picture.